# Moving an instance from US to Europe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

some time ago i created a VM instance in the us-central1-c zone. Now i want to move this instance to europe-west4. The VM has one CPU, 2,75GB memory and a Intel Haswell CPU.Is it possible to move the instance 1 on 1 with the gcloud tool or is my configuration not supported in the europe-west4 zone?

Thanks, Mark

I've read the instructions on the GCP help pages but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: As for now, Haswell CPU is only available on `europe-west1`, `us-east1` and `us-central1` regions : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/. But do you have a specific reason to use this kind of CPU? Moreover, are there some processes running on your `us-central1` VM that you want to migrate? Do you accept downtimes during this migration?

Comment: No specific reason for the CPU. On the VM i'm running a controller to manage my networks, downtimes don't matter

Answer (score 2):

#### VM Configuration migration only

If you only want to migrate the VM configuration, the easiest way is to migrate your VM directly from the Console via the [Create similar](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance) button.

After clicking the button, just change the region to `europe-west4`.

That creates a VM with the same configuration as the previous one (exceptly the region in you case), but that does not migrate your processes (neither the data stored on the existing VM by the way). In your case, it seems like this is the easiest solution since downtimes don't matter.

#### Migrating services using disk snapshots

If migrating the services/installed applications on the existing VM is required, then you can [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the existing VM's boot disk, and [restore](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots) it on the new VM (in the other zone).

Comment: I guess that means i have to create a new setup for the controller or can i run a backup from my current VM?

Comment: You can create a snapshot of the existing VM's disk, and restore it to another VM : see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these procedures on how to migrate your instance from US to Europe.

1. Please create a snapshot from your VM instance [1].
2. Create disk using the snapshot you created

   a. Go to the Snapshots page in the Google Cloud Platform Console.

   b. Enter a snapshot Name.

   c. Optionally, enter a Description of the snapshot.

   d. Under Source disk, select an existing disk from which you want to create a snapshot.

   e. Optionally, you can specify a custom storage location.

   f. Click Create to create the snapshot.
3. Create an image using the newly created disk [2].
4. Create a new instance using the newly created custom image then make sure to change the region and zone of the instance [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Yeah i 'accidentally' found this option this morning when i followed the instructions of @norbjd duplicating my VM. Works perfect so far. Thanks for all of the information!